# Accessing states of an Akka Actor through messages

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to access the state of a particular actor through messaging. What I don't know is how I can retrieve the state of the actor. Here, I need to access the state variable of Node, state1. I want to avoid using promises/futures in the code. How should I go about modifying this code if I want to do that?

```
class Node extends Actor {
   val state1:Int = 4

      def receive = {
          case getState => {
             sender ! ??? //How should I send the 'state1' to the sender?
          }
       }
}

class Master extends Actor {

  def recieve = {
    case someCase(node_actor:ActorRef) => {
      // My aim here is to get the "state1" from node actor into var 's'
      var s:Int = node_actor ! getState
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you write why you want to avoid using future ?

Comment: It's a constraint in the actual implementation which prevents me from using them. The best way I can describe it is that it 'breaks' beyond a particular number of actors and I want to use as many as i can.

Comment: Note that you are not obliged to enclose your multiline `case` in braces, just indenting several lines after `case` line is sufficient

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the suggestion,

Answer (score 1):

Actors are designed perfectly to avoid manual handling of `scala.concurrent.` things.
Just separate request and response handling into different `receive` cases:

```
class Node extends Actor {
  import Node._
  val state1: Int = 4

  def receive: Receive = {
    case getState =>
      sender ! State(state1)

  }
}

class Master extends Actor {
  import Master._
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Action(node) =>
      // My aim here is to get the "state1" from node actor into var 's'
      node ! Node.GetState

    case Node.State(state) =>
      // do something with state
  }
}

object Master {
  case class Action(node: ActorRef)
}

object Node {
  case object GetState
  case class State(state: Int)
}
```

Sometimes you could have also some intermediate values calculated and don't want to do something until you'll get the answer but being unreachable also is not acceptable. So you could just wait for node response in separate `Receive` while stashing incoming messages, like this:

```
class Master extends Actor with Stash {
  import Master._
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Action(node) =>
      val intermediate = scala.util.Random.nextLong()
      node ! Node.GetState
      context.become(waitingForState(calc = intermediate), discardOld = false)
  }

  def waitingForState(calc: Long): Receive = {
    case Node.State(state) =>
      // do something with state and calc
      context.unbecome()
      unstashAll()
    case _ => stash()
  }
}
```

Comment: I created the Master actor just to make my question a clearer, the Node is the only class I have in my implementation and the communication and passing of states occurs between these node actors. This solution seems like it would work for that as well.